# Expandablelistview change drawable

Tags: android, background, expandablelistview

I have a Group item in an expandablelistview

```
if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.elvcitiesgroupitemopt,
                null);
    }
```

How can I Change in getgroupview the Background (drawable) of a textview?

Answer (score 0):

Found out myself - here for all who think about the same

```
TVSet.setBackground( context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mbutt_setup1));
```